# Inserting into database based on a chosen model EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

So I am building an application where users will upload a file and I will insert its values into an existing database.

I have been able to scaffold the existing database and so I have all the models of the existing database. Here comes my problem

I can ask the user to tell me which table they want the file to be on so I can use the model to do the insert. However, how I map the value to the model depends on the model. So if I go by my line of thinking, I would have code n ways of insertions where n is the number of models in my database. Of course this isn't efficient. What would be a better approach?

If you aren't following me, my database has tables

```
1. Test 
2. Test2
3. Test 3
```

So my models folder has

```
1. Test.cs
2. Test2.cs
3. Test3.cs
```

Test may have 3 columns and Test2 may have 10 columns. So currently after I parse the file and the user indicates Test table, I use Test.cs model to insert into the database. That function currently is different from the insertion function when I am using Test2.cs model to insert into the database. Obviously I can't be doing this for each model. Whats the sensible approach?

Comment: It sounds like the user needs to select the table, and then when they upload the file you need to deserialize that into a `List<TestX>` and bulk insert that.

Comment: @JSteward they are mainly .xlsx files so when you say deserializing, I am parsing the files myself, I don't know of any other way to handle that